# How to display system information in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++

I am writing a console application in visual c++, and I want to display the system information like one displayed when we right click on Computer icon on desktop. I want to display the information like name of processor, its speed, RAM (how much used and how much free), hard drive (whether it is fixed or removable), name of computer, Windows OS version and edition name, etc. Help appreciated.

Comment: Too unspecific. `sysdm.cpl` displays lots of information, it's unclear which one you're interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is different function for that. If you are on Windows and are looking for the windows version : this function should be ok : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And for the hardware information you can find some of them thanks to this function : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Hope this helps